# How to handle shared projects in multiple repos Git VisualStudio Solutions

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

**How to handle shared projects in multiple repos Git VisualStudio Solutions?**

For instance I have 3 projects:

1. Project_1
2. Project_2
3. CommonSharedProject

Earlier in TFS, I use to have a single repository (Generics) for all
 the project thus it was easy for me to share "CommonSharedProject"
 between the other two.

Now I have created 2 different Git Repository, i.e a.

1. Generic.Sender(contains Project_1)
2. Generic.Reciever(contians Projetc_2)

**Now how to handle "CommonSharedProject"?**

- 1st approach is that I can create one more repo for this and create NuGet packages for the common codes. But doing so will consume extra
  time and effort in doing minor changes. Please suggest some good
  approach.

Comment: Do you solve this issue with submodules?

Answer (score 4):

Use Git [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) or [subtrees](https://www.atlassian.com/blog/git/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree). A submodule is basically a pointer to a remote repository within an existing repository.